# AttributeError: exp not found

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, networkx, exponential

```
    n=sc.shape(A)[0]                   
    sim=sc.eye(n)           
    I=sc.eye(n)
    P= normalize(A, norm='l1', axis=0)          
    Q=P*(1-np.exp(-A))
```

A is an adjacency matrix created by the code:

```
df=pd.read_csv('training.csv')
G=nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df,'node1','node2','weight')

A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
```

The error I am getting :

```
File "ROC_final.py", line 36, in ASCOSplus
   Q=P*(1-np.exp(-A))
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 647, in __getattr__
   raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
AttributeError: exp not found
```

note :I have tried the solution A= A.astype(float) as suggested by SO answer too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A` is a scipy sparse matrix.  Such a matrix does not implement the `exp` function, because that would convert all the 0s to 1s, resulting in a densely populated matrix.

To do your calculation using a sparse matrix, you can write `1 - np.exp(-A)` as `-(np.exp(-A) - 1) = -np.expm1(-A)`.  That is, replace

```
Q=P*(1-np.exp(-A))
```

with

```
Q = -P*np.expm1(-A)
```

[`expm1(x)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expm1.html) is equivalent to `exp(x) - 1`.   That function maps zero to zero, so it is a "safe" element-wise function for sparse matrices.

The scipy sparse matrices have an `expm1()` method (which `np.expm1` eventually calls), so you could also write that line as

```
Q = P*(-A).expm1()
```